# how do i match a space with two shell variables inside awk in just one match function

Tags: shell, unix, awk, solaris, nawk

I have a command:

```
ls -l | nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 '{if(match($0,d1)) print $0}'
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        12 Sep 26 11:36 file1
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        14 Sep 26 11:37 file2
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:46 file3
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:44 file4
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:50 file5
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 11:00 file6
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 25 11:00 file7
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 14:22 ksh
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody       208 Sep 26 16:31 test.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody        62 Sep 26 15:15 test2.sh*
```

But when i use the below:

```
ls -l | nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 '{if(match($0,d1 d2)) print $0}'
```

Its not giving me any output!!

As you can see there is a space between Sep and 26 and i am using the same space in regex to match the string "Sep 26".
could nybody pls help?

I am expecting output to be:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        12 Sep 26 11:36 file1
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        14 Sep 26 11:37 file2
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:46 file3
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:44 file4
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:50 file5
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 11:00 file6
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 14:22 ksh
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody       208 Sep 26 16:31 test.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody        62 Sep 26 15:15 test2.sh*
```

Comment: What output did you expect it to produce?

Comment: I am surprised to see a downvote!!!i think the question is very clear.I am trying to search fro files whose date is Sep 26..I am expecting the output to be only files whose date with 'ls -l' is Sep 26.Downvoter.Pls dare to comment.

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the `"d1 d2"`?

Comment: I have tried "d1 d2".This will actually search for sting "d1 d2" but not for "Sep 26"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kent$  echo "-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        12 Sep 26 11:36 file1
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        14 Sep 26 11:37 file2
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:46 file3
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:44 file4
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:50 file5
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 11:00 file6
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 25 11:00 file7
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 14:22 ksh
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody       208 Sep 26 16:31 test.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody        62 Sep 26 15:15 test2.sh*
"|awk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 'BEGIN{x=d1" "d2}{ if(match($0,x))print $0;}' 

-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        12 Sep 26 11:36 file1
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody        14 Sep 26 11:37 file2
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:46 file3
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:44 file4
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 10:50 file5
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 11:00 file6
-rw-rw-r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Sep 26 14:22 ksh
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody       208 Sep 26 16:31 test.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 nobody   nobody        62 Sep 26 15:15 test2.sh*
```

Comment: Cool..Thanks a million kent.It worked.Actually i tried this But the problem with mine was d1' 'd2.Somehow  it did not work

Comment: @Rahul, it did not work because you are using single quotes to enclose your awk script: you need awk to see the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user and group names don't contain spaces, here's the Awk way of doing this:

```
ls -l | nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 '{if(match($6, d1) && match($7, d2)) print $0}'
# NOTE                                 ----^^           ----^^
```

Comment: I already tried this before posting this question.And it works too.My actual need is how do i match a space with two shell variables insdie awk in just one match function.